# Bootstrap carousel resetting to default settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been working on a bootstrap carousel that has one major issue remaining.

A pause feature is required and this is working correctly when used, but when focus moves from the pause button the carousel resets to default settings and begins cycling again.

I've tried two more methods of stopping this behavior that haven't worked; changing the interval rather than calling pause and making the pause button set a flag that will hit a `setInterval` for the window that triggers the pause.

Is there a better method to halt the carousel cycling permanently when the pause button is pressed?

The page also uses the adobe mega menu, which I included the scripts for in case they are causing the issue.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- content starts here -->
        <div class="content">
            <center>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="EXCEL 2015">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt="EEO Programs">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="Place hold">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="Flower">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </a>

                    <!-- Play and Pause -->
                    <div id="carouselButtons">
                        <input type="button" class="btn start-slide" value="Play" id='playButton'>
                        <input type="button" class="btn pause-slide" value="Pause" id='pauseButton'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Nav menu scripts -->
    <script>
        $("nav:first").accessibleMegaMenu({
            /* prefix for generated unique id attributes, which are required 
               to indicate aria-owns, aria-controls and aria-labelledby */
            uuidPrefix: "accessible-megamenu",

            /* css class used to define the megamenu styling */
            menuClass: "nav-menu",

            /* css class for a top-level navigation item in the megamenu */
            topNavItemClass: "nav-item",

            /* css class for a megamenu panel */
            panelClass: "sub-nav",

            /* css class for a group of items within a megamenu panel */
            panelGroupClass: "sub-nav-group",

            /* css class for the hover state */
            hoverClass: "hover",

            /* css class for the focus state */
            focusClass: "focus",

            /* css class for the open state */
            openClass: "open"
        });
    </script>
    <!-- carousel scripts -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 2000,
                pause: "false"
                });
            });

        $('#playButton').click(ClickOnPlayButton);

        function ClickOnPlayButton(){
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
            }

        $('#pauseButton').click(ClickOnPauseButton);

        function ClickOnPauseButton(){
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
            }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep the carousel cycling even on mouse-over (users can always come back to a particular slide by clicking the navigation buttons in the carousel). Then use play and pause buttons to pause.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 2000,
            pause: "none"
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to load `<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>` separately. It is part of the standard bootstrap.js.

There is no `pause: "false"` in carousel. You set `interval:false` instead.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/nL8z7pv6/) that should work for you.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 2000  // setting interval:false will pause carousel on load 
            });
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');


    $('#playButton').click(ClickOnPlayButton);

    function ClickOnPlayButton(){
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 2000});
        }

    $('#pauseButton').click(ClickOnPauseButton);

    function ClickOnPauseButton(){
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
        }

 });
```

Comment: When I remove `pause: 'false'` clicking the pause button resets the carousel to a default interval that is not the one that was initialized and fails to pause it.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are saying here. There is no `pause:"false"`. If you want to pause the carousel on load without using `interval:false' then  just add `` $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');' after your initial carousel call. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: Sorry about that. To be more clear. I inserted the code you posted. The carousel starts paused, then immediately reverts to cycling at a default value. I change the value of `interval: 2000` to `interval: 20` to make sure it wasn't. The play button changed the cycle speed, but the pause button did not pause the cycle. It is still triggering, it just has no effect on the carousel.

Comment: [The `data-ride="carousel"` attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the same carousel.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage)